# ASP.NET 5 and Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, silverlight-5.0, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building simple LOB application (online restaurant reservation application) and i want to support multiple client side application types like web site, windows desktop application, android application etc. So i think that best way to design system is to separate `ASP.NET 5 WebApi` which will provide interaction with database, authorization and stuff like that and than build separate solution with projects for client applications which will consume that API. One of those client applications would be `Silverlight` application. Problem is, how i consume my API from `Silverlight` application. I can't find any information to link `Silverlight` with `ASP.NET 5. All i got is`MVC6`. Is it better to create`ASP.NET MVC6`application, implement my APIs there and host`Sliverlight` in that project or to separate it like i described?

Comment: Why don't you use MVC instead of Silverlight?

Comment: I just like Silverlight.. I find writing XAML code, MVVM stuff, Caliburn.Micro etc much more convenient than HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is dead, but it can easily consume REST API so why cannot it work with ASP.NET Core 1.0?

There is no need to have special documentation.

Comment: Well that is what i wanted to hear, is it dead or not.. Why is it dead? It can work with ASP.NET Core 1.0 but can't be hosted in ASP.NET 5 application. I have to create old ASP project to host it. That's why i ask. Should i just give up on Silverlight and use some other front end stuff or not.

Comment: @VladimirDjurdjevic I would be surprised that you haven't given it up. With all browser updates in the past 24 months, Silverlight cannot run by default in so many cases.

Comment: I didn't know that :D I am not web developer, just a student so i am not in sync with everything that happens in web wold.. I have lots of expirience with WPF so i figured out that Silverlight would be best way to go to finish project fast..

Comment: @VladimirDjurdjevic to develop for all computing platforms, mobile, desktop, server and so on, JavaScript and HTML win out due to wide support it receives. Silverlight and Flash on the other side, have been obsolete due to their absence on non desktop platforms.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you!